# Change from C compiler to C++ compiler causes compiler errors for MSP430 firmware

Tags: c++, c, embedded, msp430

I am trying to compile a tried and true piece of firmware for the Texas Instruments MSP430 micro-controller with a new compiler (a C++ compiler, under Visual Studio using VisualGDB).

All prior versions of this firmware were compiled with a C compiler, with zero errors and zero warnings. The change from a C compiler to a C++ compiler must be the reason for my problem.  (The code compiled with the C compiler has been running without problems for five years.)

Given this code snippet:

```
#include <msp430x14x.h>
WDTCTL = WDTPW+WDTHOLD;
```

I get this error:

error:  'WDTCTL' does not name a type   c:\msptest\LedBlink\LedBlink.cpp

WDTCLT is declared in msp430x14x.h.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: #define WDTCTL_               0x0120    /* Watchdog Timer Control */

sfrw(WDTCTL, WDTCTL_);

Comment: That is code that doesn't comply to standards. You need to add the type `int` to that declaration.

Comment: C is *not* a subset of C++. There's no reason to expect this to work properly, even if it compiles. There are many subtle and weird differences between C and C++. For example `'a'` has the type `char` in C++ and `int` in C.

Comment: The define you gave us defines WDTCTL_. How is WDTCTL defined? Also can you give us a little more context around the `WDTCTL = WDTPW+WDTHOLD;`? Is it in a function? Is it globally declared?

Comment: Visual Studio (the IDE) is irrelevant here if you are using an MSP430 targeted cross-compiler, and its mere mention will cause confusion.  If you are using GDB, the presumably the compiler is GCC?  C++ is unlikely to be the problem, the code more likely uses compiler/target specific extensions that are neither C not C++, and not supported by compilers from different vendors.

Comment: You need to clearly define both the C compiler (vendor/version) and the C++ compiler.  Add the information to the question not as a comment - same goes for the previous comment you have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all that responded.  The responses are helpful beyond the question that I asked.

I have found, and corrected, the problem.  The problem was, I must admit, a careless error on my part.  I cut and pasted code from a completed C program into a test program, omitting

int main()

Thus, the assignment statements that the compiler complained about were in the incorrect scope of the source code.

I posted my question prematurely.

That said, your answers are most helpful in making a decision to move ahead with using the GCC compiler (with Visual Studio as the IDE), or using the same compiler that I used for all previous versions of this firmware.  I learned much from the set of answers you provided.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Two things are possible:

- msp430x14x.h provided with each compiler are different - there is no standard form for such a header and each vendor may define them differently.
- You are using the header from one compiler with another and it uses incompatible compiler extensions or syntax.

There is no doubt a great deal of compiler specific or "macro magic" going on here - what you need to look at is exactly how these macros are expanded by the pre-processor.  The compiler is complaining about the expanded code, not the source you have posted.

The pre-processor has been used here to create syntax that would not otherwise be valid C or C++ so without consideration of the expansion, not much can be determined.  And since each compiler may supply a different msp430x14x.h, without knowing exactly what C and what C++ compiler were used, not a lot can be said on that either.  Remember that the *full* expansion must be considered - so if a macro is defined in terms of other macros, they too must be expanded.  GCC has a n option top output the pre-processor output, or you can run the pre-processor separately directly (the executable is "cpp").

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `WDTCTL` is defined using `sfrw`, and although not shown in your code, `sfrw` is defined in [iomacros.h](http://mspgcc.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzr/mspgcc/mspgcc-core/annotate/397/msp430-libc/include/iomacros.h) as an inline asm statement.  Clearly inline asm is going to be processor dependent and what works for msp430 won't work in visual studio.

Comment: He appears to be using Visual Studio as and IDE, but GCC as the compiler.  I think Visual Studio is a bit of a red-herring here.